# Is there a way to set dynamically value of a parameter of an .env file in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus, microprofile

I have an .env file that contains;

```
twitch.api.authKey=Bearer *************
```

As authKey expires about 60days, I need to dynamically set value of the property in .env file. Is it possible to do that in Quarkus?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I saw one issue about [automatically load config source and mark it dynamic or not](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/issues/41) . I believe this is what you want. I also saw [this issue Improve the support of dynamic config sources](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/issues/395). I understood that the implementer of Microprofile Config can create one cache policy for the loaded properties.

Comment: There's one topic about [ConfigSource and Mutable Data on the Microprofile Config specification](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-config-1.4/microprofile-config-spec.html#_configsource_and_mutable_data). But I don't know how Quarkus implements this cache.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by Quarkus. The `.env` file is loaded and cached on application startup.

It is possible to implement your own custom `ConfigSource` that reloads configuration (or just reads the config everytime it is required). Check here: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-extending-support#custom-config-source